# Threads and pointers (Understanding how threads work)

Tags: c++, multithreading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to create threads of member functions that are accessed via pointers to objects.

So  I have

```
AbstractBaseClass* object1 = new ChildClass;
```

then I want to make a thread of `object1->foo();`

so I try

```
thread t1(object->foo(variable));
```

but it says "no instance of constructor std::thread::thread matches the argument list arguments types are void." When I hover over object1.

On compile it says,

```
error C2664: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'void' to 'std::thread &&'
1>          Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
```

I've tried making the `foo()` a type thread (not sure if that is correct) and it gets rid of the error but instead gives, no return for for type thread of which I am not returning anything cause I don't know what to return for thread.

How do I tackle this?

It isn't homework, just a learning experience for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::thread` follows the syntax of `std::bind`, so the correct invocation is

```
std::thread t(&AbstractBaseClass::foo, object, variable)
```

The first one is called a *pointer to member function*. The above will copy by value the parameters passed to it. If you need pass by reference, use `std::ref`, like

```
std::thread t(&AbstractBaseClass::foo, object, std::ref(variable))
```

Remember the keep the lifetime of `variable` longer than the thread in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at a [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) man page.
You'll see that the constructor you need looks like it:

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

So, replace `thread t1(object->foo(variable));` by `thread t1(&class::foo, object, variable);`

This answer

Comment: Does this work? I'm assuming that `foo` is a member function.

Comment: Got it working, forgot to pass my object. Working on a simulator and it seems wise to get into running certain functions concurrently.

Thanks for the help!